# Sales (Service) Cloud for Slack and multiple org connections - Preferred vs Default. What's the difference?

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

As part of developing integrations between our SFDC orgs and the Slack apps:

- **Sales Cloud for Slack**
- **Service Cloud for Slack**

I ended up creating connections from Slack to my dev, staging, and PROD orgs.

- One of these connections is marked (in Slack) as `Preferred`, another as `Default`.
- What do these mean? Despite [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps_service_set_preferred_org.htm&type=5), the distinction is not made

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, consulting the auguries, and a few interactions with SFDC Support, I conclude the following:

### Given a single corporate Slack workspace (`mycompany`)

- Multiple SFDC orgs can send swarm (aka sales channels) -related messages to the Slack workspace provided there is a connection from the Slack app to Salesforce for the running user. Whether the connection is default, preferred, or neither doesn't matter.

  - Example: Clicking the `Link a Slack Channel` button on the Account or Opportunity page.
- However, going from Slack to Salesforce, if using the:

  - Send to Salesforce (Sales Cloud for Slack) context action
  - Send to Salesforce (Service Cloud for Slack) context action
  - Create a Record
  - Search Salesforce
  - View Pipeline
  - Create a Sales Channel
  - Or any of the slash commands available in the Sales Cloud for Slack or Service Cloud for Slack apps

### Then

- The org set as `Preferred` is the org that the Slack apps will use to do the SOQL or DML against.
- If no org connection is set as `Preferred`, then the org set as `Default` is the org that the Slack apps will use to do the SOQL or DML against.

Put another way, if you have a single Slack workspace, multiple SFDC orgs can fan-in to that workspace but from the Slack workspace, you can, within the Slack app, only interact with a single SFDC org at a time.

This might seem obvious to the reader but endless errors during the development cycle with multiple org connections, UAT, partial doc (as of V60) prompted me to memorialize this for others.

---

[image]

[image]